# Send fingerprint data from client to server on every request in Next.js 14?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I get a user fingerprint in browser like:

```js
"use client"

import FingerprintJS from "@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs"
import { useCookies } from "next-client-cookies"
import React from "react"

import { isBrowser } from "@/app/lib/isBrowser"

export const VISITOR_ID = "vid"

export function Fingerprint() {
    const cookies = useCookies()

    React.useEffect(() => {
        async function setFingerprint() {
            if (isBrowser()) {
                const fp = await FingerprintJS.load()
                const { visitorId } = await fp.get()
                cookies.set(VISITOR_ID, visitorId)
            }
        }

        setFingerprint()
    }, [cookies])
    return null
}
```

Now I want `visitorId` to be sent on every request I make.

What's the easiest way to do it rather than attaching it to every fetch api call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `zustand` to store the fingerprint data locally. Can also add it to localstorage. And then send it via every request. Works for now.

#### src/app/store/zustand.ts

```js
import { create } from "zustand"

type Store = {
    fingerprint: string
    setFingerprint: (fingerprint: string) => void
}

export const useStore = create<Store>()((set) => ({
    fingerprint: "",
    setFingerprint: (fingerprint) => set({ fingerprint }),
}))
```

#### src/app/components/Fingerprint.tsx

```
"use client"

import React from "react"
import { hasWindow } from "std-env"

import { useStore } from "@app/store/zustand"

export function Fingerprint() {
    const { setFingerprint } = useStore()

    React.useEffect(() => {
        async function fn() {
            if (hasWindow) {
                const { getFingerprint } = await import("@thumbmarkjs/thumbmarkjs")
                const visitorId = await getFingerprint()
                setFingerprint(visitorId)
            }
        }

        fn()
    }, [setFingerprint])
    return null
}
```

#### src/app/components/LoginForm.tsx

```
"use client"

import { useStore } from "@app/store/zustand"

export const LoginForm = async () => {
    const { fingerprint } = useStore()

    const response = await fetch("/api/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: 'dead@man.com', fingerprint }),
    })
}
```